# how to truly turn off LaTex output in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

My group is using Doxygen 1.8.5 on RHEL7 to generate HTML-only documentation for a large C++ project. We only want HTML documentation and do not desire any other output format. The project's Doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) carries the following settings which differ from the default (among others, of course):

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="../Docs"
GENERATE_HTML=YES
GENERATE_LATEX=NO
```

When we run Doxygen with this config file, towards the end of processing, errors start coming to screen from LaTeX components, and processing is held up until the user hits enter a bunch of times to get past these errors, e.g.

```
...

sh: epstopdf: command not found
error: Problems running epstopdf. Check your TeX installation!
Generating graph info page...
Generating directory documentation...
</home/abilich/Src/GNSS_Software/Lib/LibgpsC++/>:3: warning: Found unknown command `\reference'
</home/abilich/Src/GNSS_Software/Lib/LibgpsC++/>:2: warning: Found unknown command `\reference'
</home/abilich/Src/GNSS_Software/Lib/LibgpsC++/>:2: warning: Found unknown command `\reference'
Generating bitmaps for formulas in HTML...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./_formulas.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))))
No file _formulas.aux.
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.53 \[ \Vert v - w \Vert \leqslant
                                    p\,\min(\Vert v\Vert, \Vert w\Vert). \]
? 

...

! Undefined control sequence.
l.533 $ \vert singular value \vert \leqslant
                                             threshold \times \vert max sing...

? 
[177] [178] (./_formulas.aux) )
Output written on _formulas.dvi (178 pages, 20576 bytes).
Transcript written on _formulas.log.
error: Problems running latex. Check your installation or look for typos in _formulas.tex and check _formulas.log!
Generating image form_0.png for formula
sh: gs: command not found
error: Problem running ghostscript gs -q -g60x50 -r384x384x -sDEVICE=ppmraw -sOutputFile=_form0.pnm -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -- _form0.ps. Check your installation!
Generating index page...
/home/abilich/Src/GNSS_Software/Doxy/mainpage.h:15: warning: image file GNSSSoftwareTimeline.png is not found in IMAGE_PATH: assuming external image.
Generating page index...
Generating module index...
Generating namespace index...
Generating namespace member index...
```

I want to create a Doxyfile that runs without user intervention and does not throw LaTeX errors. Where have I gone astray?

Comment: Version 1.8.5 is a bit old (August 2013), I would install the current version. Back to the LaTeX problem, it is possible to use MATHJAX for the rendering of the formulas (see configuration options). Regarding the error i the formula, I would at least check what is wrong here as it probably will anyway show up in the output.

Comment: USE_MATHJAX=YES eliminated the LaTeX errors, thank you @albert.

Comment: Did you check if all the formulas are working (especially the one throwing the error)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [@albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657886/albert)'s comment, actually the newest version of doxygen did support to turn latex generation off by setting `GENERATE_LATEX=NO`:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# If the GENERATE_LATEX tag is set to YES, doxygen will generate LaTeX output.
# The default value is: YES.

GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
```

<strike>The parameter `USE_PDFLATEX` in your config file should set to **NO** (the default value is **YES**)</strike>

> ```
> # If the USE_PDFLATEX tag is set to YES, doxygen will use the engine as
> # specified with LATEX_CMD_NAME to generate the PDF file directly from the LaTeX
> # files. Set this option to YES, to get a higher quality PDF documentation.
> #
> # See also section LATEX_CMD_NAME for selecting the engine.
> # The default value is: YES.
> # This tag requires that the tag GENERATE_LATEX is set to YES.
> USE_PDFLATEX           = NO
> ```

Comment: You probably pointed here to a small problem in doxygen (thanks) but for the original question I don't think it has any influence (the problem there seems to be due toa formula).

Comment: I just investigated the problem a bit further the line `if ( (format==PlantumlManager::PUML_EPS) && (Config_getBool(USE_PDFLATEX)) )` and when `GENERATE_LATEX=NO` there will be no request with `format == PUML_EPS` and thus when `GENERATE_NO` this part isn't entered at all. There is no need to disable this part by setting `USE_PDFLATEX=NO`.

Comment: @albert, You're right, the version 1.8.20 did support to turn off LATEX completely by setting `GENERATE_LATEX=NO`